# Weird issue - dimensional array input in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I wrote a program to check wether a square `n*n` matrix is "perfect", meaning each line and row hold exactly one instance of each number from 1 to `n`.

I also wrote a main function to allocate memory for a given size and receive values of that matrix from the user.

It seems to work fine, except when I chose 4 for size and input this matrix:
`{{1,2,3,4},{2,1,4,3},{3,4,2,1),{4,3,1,2}}`.

I get the matrix `{{1,2,3,4},{2,**3**,4,3},{3,4,**3**,1},{4,3,1,2}}`.

It looks like an input thing, but I can`t find what`s wrong :(

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

int IsPerfect(int *arr, int size);

void main() {
    int size = 0, i = 0, j = 0, vol = 0;
    printf("please enter matrix size, 0 to exit:\n");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    printf("size is :%d\n", size);
    while (size != 0) {  //loop for allocating and inputing ,matrix
        int *pmatrix = (int *)malloc(size*size * sizeof(int));
        printf("please input matrix:\n");
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                printf("[%d][%d]\n", i, j);
                scanf("%d", ((pmatrix + i) + j));  //storing matrix values
            }
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
                printf("[%d]", *((pmatrix + i) + j));  //printing matrix
            printf("\n");
        }
        IsPerfect(pmatrix, size);  //perfect check
        free(pmatrix);
        printf("please enter matrix size, 0 to exit:\n");
        scanf("%d", &size);
    }
    printf("bye bye!\n");
}

int IsPerfect(int *arr, int size) {
    int i = 0, j = 0, w = 0, perf = 1;
    int *check = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);

    for (w = 0; w < size; w++) {  //horizontal check
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
            *(check + i) = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
            for (j = 1; j <= size; j++)
                if (*((arr + w) + i) == j)
                    *(check + j - 1) = *(check + j - 1) + 1;
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (*(check + i) == 0 || *(check + i) > 1)
                perf = 0;
    }
    for (w = 0; w < size; w++) {  //vertical check
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
            *(check + i) = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
            for (j = 1; j <= size; j++)
                if (*((arr + i) + w) == j)
                    *(check + j - 1) = *(check + j - 1) + 1;
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (*(check + i) == 0 || *(check + i) > 1)
                perf = 0;
    }


    if (perf == 1)
        printf("the matrix is perfect\n");
    if (perf == 0)
        printf("the matrix is not perfect\n");
    free(check);
    return perf;
}
```

Comment: Don't you want `(pmatrix + i * size)` to get the right row? And then add `j` for the column. Your `(pmatrix + i) + j` is incorrect because it's a one-dimensional array. The result is you overwrite values already entered.

Comment: @ryyker thanks, but I have been downvoted before and told "I should know better" for posting an answer that mentions only one problem. There may be more issues that need following through too. I haven't analysed the whole program, but it looks as though there as similar issues in function `IsPerfect`.

Comment: @Nitzane note that `(pmatrix + i) + j` is the same as `pmatrix + i + j` which is the same as `(pmatrix + j) + i` so hopefully you can see there is no distinction between row and column, the way you wrote it.

Comment: that's the thing - i tried replacing my code with yours and it behaves even worse:( is there a way you could show that to me in the context of my code?

Comment: the posted code is missing the statement: `#include <stdlib.h>` to expose the function prototypes for: `malloc()` and `free()`

Comment: OT: regarding: `int size = 0, i = 0, j = 0, vol = 0;`  Please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: regarding: `int *pmatrix = (int *)malloc(size*size * sizeof(int));`  1) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code.  Suggest removing the cast.  2) the parameter type for `malloc()` is `size_t` (an unsigned long int).  However, `size` is declared as an `int`.  This leaves the code vulnerable to a 'unintented' sign change of the parameter.  Suggest declaring `size` as `size_t` rather than `int`

Comment: The posted code does not compile!  Amongst (possible) other problems, it is missing the statement: `#include <stdlib.h>` to expose the prototypes for functions: `malloc()` and `free()`

Comment: regarding: `void main() {`  There are only two valid signature for `main()`  they are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] );`  Notice they all have a return type of `int`

Comment: When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc()`, `calloc()`, and/or `realloc()`: always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, then call `perror( "malloc failed" );` followed by: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  Note: exit() and EXIT_FAILURE are exposed by the statement: `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: See: [C11 Standard - §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup(p1)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p1). See also: [What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/). But note: In a freestanding environment (in which C program execution may take place without any benefit of an operating system), the name and type of the function called at program startup are implementation-defined. See: [C11 Standard - 5.1.2.1 Freestanding environment](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. uses appropriate horizontal and vertical spacing for readability
3. properly checks for (and handles) errors
4. uses `size_t` for the index types as those values should never be less than 0 and better matches the expectations of the `malloc()` function
5. uses statements like: `for ( size_t col = 1; col <= size; col++ )` to limit the `scope` of local variables to the enclosing `for()` loop body
6. corrects the problem with the input sequence, where the method of accessing the matrix elements was not correct
7. does NOT correct the problem within the `check()` function, where, again, the method of accessing the matrix elements is not correct
8. the problem in the `check()` function is the addressing of the elements of the array
9. renamed variables `i` and `j` for better understanding.  `i ==> row` and `j ==> col`

Note:  this statement is typical of the problems in the code:

```
if ( *(check + row) == 0 || *(check + row) > 1 )
```

because `check` is at [0][0] so when adding `row` that is indexing across the first row I.E. [0][0]...[0][3].  Not what the code needs to do to check a column of the matrix

Perhaps you meant:

```
if ( *(check + size*row + col) == 0 || *(check + size*row + col) > 1 )
```

which would index [0][col]... [3][col]

And now, the proposed code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int IsPerfect( int *arr, size_t size );

int main( void ) 
{
    size_t size;

    printf("please enter matrix size, 0 to exit:\n");
    scanf("%zu", &size);
    printf("size is :%zu\n", size);

    while ( size != 0 ) 
    {  //loop for allocating and inputing ,matrix
        int *pmatrix = malloc( size*size * sizeof(int) );
        if( ! pmatrix )
        {
            perror( "malloc failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        printf( "please input matrix:\n" );

        for ( size_t row = 0; row < size; row++)
        {
            for ( size_t col = 0; col < size; col++) 
            {
                printf( "[%zu][%zu]\n", row, col );
                if( scanf( "%d", &pmatrix[ (size*row) + col ]) != 1 )  //storing matrix values row by row
                {
                    fprintf( stderr, "scanf for matrix entry failed\n" );
                    free( pmatrix );
                    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                }
            }
        }

        for ( size_t row = 0; row < size; row++) 
        {
            for ( size_t col = 0; col < size; col++)
            {
                printf( "[%d]", pmatrix[ row*size + col ] );  //printing matrix
            }
            printf( "\n" );
        }

        IsPerfect( pmatrix, size );  //perfect check
        free( pmatrix );

        printf( "please enter matrix size, 0 to exit:\n" );
        scanf( "%zu", &size );
    }
    printf( "bye bye!\n" );
}


int IsPerfect( int *arr, size_t size ) 
{
    int  perf = 1;

    int *check = malloc( sizeof(int) * size );
    if( !check )
    {
        perror( "malloc failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    for ( size_t w = 0; w < size; w++ ) 
    {  //horizontal check
        for ( size_t row = 0; row < size; row++ )
        {
            *(check + row) = 0;
        }

        for ( size_t row = 0; row < size; row++ )
        {
            for ( size_t col = 1; col <= size; col++ )
            {
                if ( *((arr + w) + row) == (int)col )
                {
                    *(check + col - 1) = *(check + col - 1) + 1;
                }
            }
        }

        for ( size_t row = 0; row < size; row++ )
        {
            if ( *(check + size*row) == 0 || *(check + size*row) > 1 )
            {
                perf = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    for ( size_t w = 0; w < size; w++ ) 
    {  //vertical check
        for ( size_t row = 0; row < size; row++ )
        {
            *(check + size*row) = 0;
        }

        for ( size_t w = 0; w < size; w++ )
        {
            for ( size_t col = 1; col <= size; col++ )
            {
                 // why expect a position reference in the matrix to be the same as the content
                if ( *((arr + size*col) + w) == (int)col )      
                {
                    *(check + col - 1) = *(check + col - 1) + 1; //  causes seg fault
                }
            }
        }

        for ( size_t row = 0; row < size; row++ )
        {
            if ( *(check + row) == 0 || *(check + row) > 1 )
            {
                perf = 0;
            }
        }
    }


    if (perf == 1)
    {
        printf( "the matrix is perfect\n" );
    }

    else
    {
        printf( "the matrix is not perfect\n" );
    }

    free( check );
    return perf;
}
```

Note: a run of the proposed code and using the OPs data, results in:

```
[1][2][3][4]
[2][1][4][3]
[3][4][2][1]
[4][3][1][2]
```

so the input operation is now correct, but the `check()` function is still way off (and results in a seg fault event on (approx) line number 109:

```
if ( *((arr + size*col) + w) == (int)col )
```

Comment: This fixes the problem i was having with matrix inputing! Thank you